# How to define timeout per function in host.json?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have many functions and most of them I want to have a timeout of 30 seconds. Yet there is one where the timeout needs to be about 2.30 min.

Is there a way to configure hosts.json to reflect that?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible within a single function app. However, you should be able to split the 2:30 function out into a separate function app. If it's an HTTP triggered function then use Azure Functions Proxies on the main app to forward the endpoint to the new app.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be not possible via the host.json file. According to the documentation the timeout is set for all functions

> Indicates the timeout duration for all functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

But it maybe possible with durable functions timer.

> Durable Functions provides durable timers for use in orchestrator functions to implement delays or to set up timeouts on async actions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-timers#usage-for-timeout