# Setting a typescript azure durable function timeout to 10 minutes

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an azure function app with many function. One of these is a durable function (Starter, orchestrator, and activity). I want to set the timeout of my durable function (and not my other functions) to 10 minutes. From what I understand this is configurable in the host.json file.

I have configured mine as below:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error (yellow underline in VScode) under the functionTimeout stating: Property functionTimeout is not allowed.

However if I move the function time out the parent level I do not get this error. The only problem with this solution is that it will set the function timeout of all my functions, durable and non-durable, to 10 minutes. Is there a way to configure this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Host.json**:

```json
{
    "functionTimeout": "00:05:00"
}
```

[image]

Regardless of the number of functions you create, `host.json` is common Application setting file for that project and [`functionTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) is the common attribute for all the functions.

- You can change the values of Timeout in Runtime environments (dev, prod) by using the `AzureFunctionsJobHost__functionTimeout` attribute in the Application Settings Configuration to override the `host.json` file as specified in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values).

> The only problem with this solution is that it will set the function timeout of all my functions, durable and non-durable, to 10 minutes. Is there a way to configure this correctly?

It’s not possible to set the timeout per function level as stated in this SO [Issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611276/how-to-define-timeout-per-function-in-host-json) and [Issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425013/durable-function-timeout) where you can use the durable functions for implementing delays or timeouts for `async` actions and can split up the large functionality into multiple activity functions to experience better.